# Magento 2 : Schedule Status : suspended

Tags: magento2, product, cron, reindex, indexing

I'm on Magento 2.2.4 with php7. I have a cron job already set that  reindexes it all twice a day.

I usually also reindex manually and when i see a suspended index I reset it. 
But, when I do `reindex:status` I notice that the "Product Categories" index has always the Schedule status "suspended", even when i reset it and reindex it succefully it never changes. 
[image]

Any idea why, please?

system log shows this:

```
[2018-10-04 17:25:56] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 1000; Allocated memory size: 50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes. [] []
```

debug log shows this:

```
[2018-10-04 17:27:50] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://www.example.com/en-ca/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=23&material_color=114&q=custom&rs_width=150","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
```

Comment: This status appeared because of process terminated due to process killed or any fetal error. you need to see your logs for this why this process terminated without catching any exception. Error logs will help you to debug it.

Comment: i updated my post... I don't think i can see much in the logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reindexing the indexers individually solved my problem; in my case i run: php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_category

Answer (score -1):

What worked for us was to reset the stuck index as our was running by a cronjob.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_category
```